# Issue loading images with stb_image

Tags: c++, opengl

I want to load images using stb_image. I downloaded `stb_image.h` from https://github.com/nothings/stb. When I run the code:

```
string file="image.png";
int width,height,components;

unsigned char *imageData = stbi_load(file.c_str(),
        &width, &height, &components, STBI_rgb_alpha);
```

i get the following errors:

```
Main.cpp:(.text+0xa14): undefined reference to `stbi_load'
Main.cpp:(.text+0xb74): undefined reference to `stbi_image_free'
```

Comment: You should really read the documentation of the libraries you are using. Just `#include "stb_image.h"` is _not_ enough...

Comment: So what is enough?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You probably should add: `#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION` to your code before the include. This is suggested in one of the first lines of the header file.

Comment: It worked! Now I can compile it but when I try loading an image the program crashes, any ideas?

Comment: What is the error with which the program crashes?

Comment: I get a Segmentation fault. but it was caused by the next line: glTextureParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);

Comment: `glTextureParameteri` is a GL 4.5 function which must be loaded via the GL extension mechanism, and you are even using it wrong. You are probably looking for `glTexParameteri`

Comment: Thank you so much it works perfectly now!